# Comparing Pandas Dataframe to a set in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with some sales data as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bill_id': ['1001','1002','1006']})
```

I have another set with a list of bill_id:

```
{'1002', '10006', '1009'}
```

I am trying to find `bill_id` common in the Dataframe and the set and tried the below:

```
issues = list(l in set(df['bill_id']))
```

I get an error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`, wondering if I am checking it incorrectly. Expecting the output to be a list.

Expected output of set as below:

```
{'1002'}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Shir expect a list with value of `1002` as that is the common value between the Dataframe and the set

Comment: You're not iterating. `l in set(df['bill_id'])` just returns a bool. What you're looking for is a generator: `l in set(df['bill_id']) for l in other_set`. Or use intersection with sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bill_id': ['1001','1002','1006']})
bill_id = ('1002', '10006', '1009')
set(df.bill_id.values).intersection(bill_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
issues = set(df['bill_id']).intersection(other_bill_id_set)
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Convert the dict into list
2.Fetch list of unique bill_id from dataframe
3.Use set and intersection method to get common elements

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bill_id': ['1001','1002','1006']})
bill_id = list({'1002', '10006', '1009'})

bill_df = list(df['bill_id'].unique())
final_res = list(set(bill_df).intersection(bill_id))

print(final_res)
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `isin` to get the rows in your dataframe that match your other list of ids.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'bill_id': ['1001','1002','1006']})
        other_bill_ids = set({'1002', '10006', '1009'})
        df[df['bill_id'].isin(other_bill_ids)]
Out[1]:   bill_id
        1    1002
```

If all you want is a list or a set, you can do

```
In [2]: df['bill_id'][df['bill_id'].isin(other_bill_ids)].tolist()
Out[2]: {'1002'}
```

or

```
In [3]: df['bill_id'][df['bill_id'].isin(other_bill_ids)].tolist()
Out[3]: ['1002']
```